# Online WYSIWYG PDF editor

Tags: html, pdf, editor, wysiwyg

Actually i'm looking for a simple online WYSIWYG PDF editor where i can build simple formular (image,text,inputs) with drag&drop, but i could'nt find any.

Alternatively i would also accept a HTML WYSIWYG editor like ckeditor, but with an Grid option for placing absolute elements. With only absolute elements it should'nt be hard to write a PDF output out of the HTML source.
I know the `html2pdf` stuff but last time i used it (about 1 year), those scripts where horrible slow and not quite exactly.

Comment: Belongs on http://webapps.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @Koning: [Don't](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/46035/should-i-remove-tags-that-dont-contribute-to-categorizing-the-question/46037#46037) [tag](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43879/anti-tags-valid-use-or-not) [not-programming-related.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10216/can-we-disallow-the-use-of-belongs-on-xxxxxxx-and-not-programming-related-tag/10222#10222)

Comment: On webapps they're saying it belongs to stackoverflow, like first comment on this: http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/1052/what-is-the-best-wysiwyg-html-editor-closed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Google Docs](http://docs.google.com/) can [export as PDF](http://docs.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=40609).

[image: Export as PDF]

---

**UPDATE**

As your comment clarifies you would like to implement your own editor I would suggest you use [`FPDF`](http://www.fpdf.org/) which allows you to create PDFs in pure PHP without using `PDFlib`.

**Edit:** Use your favorite HTML WYSIWYG along with [dompdf](http://www.digitaljunkies.ca/dompdf/). Similar to the idea you yourself suggested.

Comment: thx for the reply, but actual i want to implement the editor to my own website, so I can make some pdf templates.

Comment: FPDF? I've given a link in the answer.

Comment: well fpdf is just for generating pdf files, i want a wysiwyg editor for generating pdf files (or a html editor (with a grid view) where i can parse the elements and then using fpdf to generate the pdf)

Comment: Favourite HTML WYSIWYG with [dompdf](http://www.digitaljunkies.ca/dompdf/)?

Comment: And [this](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1280787) has been talking about himself at some places.

Comment: thx i guess i'll try out dompdf. the last is just wysiwyg in netbeans.

Answer (score 0):

Try [Google Docs.](http://docs.google.com)

You save as PDF by opening File > Download as > PDF

Comment: thx for the reply, but actual i want to implement the editor to my own website, so I can make some pdf templates.